# How do I teleport all parts (objects) of the same name to my character?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have this script that teleports "**Object1.Object1**", "**Object1.Object2**". and "**Object3.Object3**" to your character, but in its parent "**Spawns**" there are dozen of "**Object1.Object1**"'s with the exact same name.

What can I do to my script in order for it to teleport **every** "**Object1.Object1**", "**Object2.Object2**", and "**Object3.Object3**" to my character, instead of just the first one, which is what it's doing at the moment?

```
while true do
function teleport ()
game.Workspace.Spawns.Object1.Object1.CFrame = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
game.Workspace.Spawns.Object2.Object2.CFrame = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
game.Workspace.Spawns.Object3.Object3.CFrame = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
    end
pcall( teleport )
wait()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple scenario. If you want to teleport everything, what I'd do is first, seperate all the objects you'd like to teleport into a single directroy, possibly game.ServerStorage or something. Then, what I'd do is the following:

```
game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:connect(function()
    local objects = game.ServerStorage.Objects:GetChildren()
    for i = 1,#objects do
        if objects[i]:IsA("BasePart") then
            objects[i].Parent = workspace
            objects[i].CFrame = CFrame.new(player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position)
        end
    end
end)
```

Now, for your exact scenario would be a little trickier, as it's not very well orgasnized, but what I'd do, if you would not like to change anything, is this (please note, I don't have access to Roblox Studio at the moment, so it may not work, but I'll test it when I do and give you a better response):

```
 game:GetService("RunService").RenderStepped:connect(function()
    local objects = game.Workspace.Spawns:GetChildren()
    for i = 1,#objects do
        if objects[i]:IsA("BasePart") then
            if string.sub(objects[i].Name,1,6) == "Object" then
                local child = objects[i]:GetChildren()
                for b = 1,#child do
                    if child[b] then
                        child[b].CFrame = CFrame.new(game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame.p)
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: If the Objects aren't named in increasing numerical order, and they are named after colors like "Red", "blue", "green", etc, the second script wouldn't work, so what would I do then?

Comment: Then, for the second script, you'd want to remove the "if" statement at line 5 and the end at line 9. That should give you the desired result